# My Git was disabled after I installed El Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: emacs, git

After I installed El Capitan 10.11.1 my Git was disabled. I ran my MacBook Pro and my MacBook Air in Recovery mode (Command+R) and restarted and without "csrutil disable" or without disabling my SIP my GIT started to function once again. CAN SOMEONE EXPLAIN ? How did this magic happen.

Please see the following post ...

https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/10/01/how-i-got-el-capitain-working-with-my-developer-tools/

Comment: Git is such a simple thing to reinstall -- why spin your wheels?  Perhaps a symlink was broken or something, but if you can just reinstall, it only takes a minute or two . . .

Comment: How does that link relate to your question?

Comment: I agree Git is a very easy re install. Can one explain how is it possible that the following error ... 

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer

Comment: I agree Git is a very easy re install. Can one explain how is it possible that the following error ... 

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer

rectify itself without reinstalling xcode ?